# Create back to top button using jquery facing issue with code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have fixed button on my `index.php` thats works for going to top when user is at the bottom of the page.

```
<button id="fixed-btn"></button>
```

and its css is like this.

```
#fixed-btn{
 position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px; 
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
 opacity: 0;
}
#fixed-btn.show{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

for doing so i write jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  function testScroll(ev)
  {
    if(window.pageYOffset>400)
    {
      $('#fixed-btn').addClass('show');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#fixed-btn').removeClass('show');
    }
  }
  window.onscroll=testScroll
  $("#fixed-btn").click(function()
  {
    $('html, body').animate(
    {
      scrollTop:0
    }, 1500 );
  });
```

i don't know why it is not working.button is not visible . can anyone has idea about it then please share . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you try z-index in css ?? @foram

Comment: It works fine for me. check https://jsfiddle.net/ou5rrww6/

Comment: you miss this `});` at the end

Answer (score 0):

I see your code i think this will solve your problem.replace your css by given below

```
#fixed-btn{
 position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px; 
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
 z-index: 9999;   
 opacity: 0;
}
```

you just add  `z-index: 9999;`  in this `#fixed-btn{..}`

if still face issue then let me know.